# How to redirect into HTML static page from the Spring Boot genericResponse method

Tags: html, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Im very new to the Spring boot. according to the client requirement my other member developed code segment using spring boot to get user response from here. Here is the code segment.

```
public GenericResponse updateAcceptOrReject(String password, FileAcceptStatus status) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    GenericResponse genericResponse = new GenericResponse();
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM employee WHERE pass_code = ?";

    Employee employee = null;
    try {
        employee = (Employee) jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, new Object[] { password }, new EmployeeRowMapper());
    } catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException e) {
        System.out.println("error :"+ e.getLocalizedMessage());
        employee = null;
    }catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("error :"+ e.getLocalizedMessage());
        employee = null;
    }
    // check if employee available          
    if(employee == null) {
        genericResponse.setStatusCode(200);
        genericResponse.setMessage("No employee found");
        return genericResponse;
    }
    // check acceptStatus 
    if(employee.getAccept_status() != 0) {
        genericResponse.setStatusCode(201);
        genericResponse.setMessage("You already accepted");
        return genericResponse;
    }

    String updateSql = "update employee set accept_status=? where pass_code=?";
    int[] types = {Types.INTEGER, Types.VARCHAR};

    int updatedFlag = jdbcTemplate.update(updateSql, new Object[] { status.ordinal(), password }, types);
    if(updatedFlag == 1) {
        genericResponse.setStatusCode(0);
        genericResponse.setMessage("Success");
        return genericResponse;
    }else {
        genericResponse.setStatusCode(-99);
        genericResponse.setMessage("Error occured while updating employ");
        return genericResponse;
    }
}
```

**what i want is load separate static HTML page with a Success message located in another package rather that stating Success message in genericResponse.setMessage(). likewise static pages for other messages too.**

[image]

Can anyone help me here?

Controller is like

```
 @RestController
public class HumanResourceController {

    @Autowired
    private HumanResourceService hRService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/update/status/{password:.+}/{status}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<?> updateAcceptOrReject(@PathVariable("password") String password,
            @PathVariable("status") FileAcceptStatus status) {

        GenericResponse genericResponse = hRService.updateAcceptOrReject(password, status);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(genericResponse);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **@RestController** will always return json message, so you should change it to **@Controller**, then you need to create a viewresolver to render the static html

move all your html file into /WEB-INF/

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver getViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(
            DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }    
}


@Controller
public class HumanResourceController {

    @Autowired
    private HumanResourceService hRService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/update/status/{password:.+}/{status}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String updateAcceptOrReject(@PathVariable("password") String password,
            @PathVariable("status") FileAcceptStatus status) {

        GenericResponse genericResponse = hRService.updateAcceptOrReject(password, status);
        // you can return various view according the generic response http code
        return "alreadyaccepted";
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help .